# How can I properly format dates in TypeScript to make comparisons

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to create some date variables so I can compare a date from my data source and apply conditional formatting. If the date I am returning falls within the range of these variables, I will apply a certain class in my HTML.

Here is what I have done:

```
  public today = new Date();
  public sixtyDays = new Date().setDate(this.today.getDate() + 60);
  public tenDays = new Date().setDate(this.today.getDate() + 10);
  public oneDay = new Date().setDate(this.today.getDate() + 1);
```

This returns the following (in the same order):

```
Wed Aug 21 2019 14:20:41 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)
1571606441866
1567286441866
1566508841866
```

The dates from my data source return as follows: 02/28/2021 12:00:00 AM.

What is the best way to format these dates so I can properly make comparisons?

Answer (score 0):

Just cast the date coming from the datasource in to a date format. Something like this

```
dt = new Date("dateFromDataSource")
dt = new Date("02/28/2021 12:00:00 AM")
```

After that you can check for range with normal comparison operators.